# Javascript validation in Eclipse IDE EE Mars

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Maybe is a stupid question but I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Mars and I would like to use JavaScript Development Tools for help me with Javascript code (now I have to deploy to test my javascript code).
I'm using Spring, Maven, Hibernate, Thymeleaf and Bootstrap.
I thought that in IDE for Web Developers it was included and if I go in Installation Details I see it:

[image: eclipse]

I read [javascript for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse) and follow all the steps except the installation but I can't see if in my javascript there are error.
Is it possible to have a validation for syntax and proposals? Now it seems to use Notepad++ for my code in Eclipse environment

Comment: Eclipse is not trivial when it comes to understanding how to activate particular features. The goal is to have a Javascript facet activated in your project, you shouldn't need to install anything specific to activate Javascript validation support. You can see project facets in the project properties, under the **project facets** menu option.

Comment: I tried but it gives me only an errore in a plugin javascript and not in mine

Answer (score 0):

you need to create static web Project in order to get intellisense and help for Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started)

The JSDT validator is very old and it cannot support ES5/ES6 syntax, so 
I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site).

tern.java is based on JSDT and extend it to support completion, validation for many JavaScript frameworks (Angular, jQuery, node, requirejs, etc). tern.java [supports too ECMAScript6](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-ECMAScript6-support).

tern.java provides [several linter](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter) like ESLint, JSHint which are able to validate ES5, ES6 syntax and more.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have installed Tern ide, now  Do I have to Convert To Tern Project? Can it make problems for my project?

Comment: @luca yes you must convert to tern project. Please take time to read links that I have added.