# How to add Javascript file into Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Oxygen.

I have web features already installed, I think some packages are missing for javascript files.

When I try to create a new javascript file, I see that there is no javascript file. How to add this feature into eclipse?

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: try to add new script as new file then name it as "scipt.js". you will get your script file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: You may need to install a plugin. Check this link: [Installing JavaScript Plugin to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: @CanBayar i have already installed juno, it is still missing. i can add this file manual, i want to use js template.

Comment: It looks like he already has the JavaScript Plugin (see the code-highlighting for JavaScript). He just looks in the wrong "folder" ("Web"), to create a new JavaScript-File choose: "JavaScript > JavaScript Source File"

Comment: in the Wizards `type filter text` type -> **javascript**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just look in the wrong "folder" ("Web") to create a new JavaScript-file, the proper path is "JavaScript > JavaScript Source File".

You can also take advantage of the search in the Wizards when you type the desired search term at `type filter text`.

[image: New JavaScript Source File in Eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a perspective, which is not suitable for web development.
Try opening a perspective which suits your development domain. *Web* and *Java EE* perspectives for example supports JavaScript development. If such is not available in you Eclipse installation, you have to install additional tools. Which [Eclipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) are you using?

In the right perspective you will have the *JavaScript Source File* option in the *New* pop-up dialog right clicking your project or an appropriate project folder (eg. WebContent).