# Why is the JavaScript Viewer not showing in Eclipse Editor Selection?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I am currently trying to code on Eclipse using JavaScript, but I am having a lot of troubles when tying to add JavaScript to Eclipse. I followed the instructions on this website ([JavaScript Editor Plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse)), and everything was going well until step 9 of the first part. JavaScript Viewer is not one of the offered options in Editor Selection. I am very confused as to what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance :)

Version: *Eclipse Oxygen on MacOS.* Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Comment: That answer is rather old. These days you should find that there is already a `.js` entry already in the File Associations with 'Javascript Editor' in the Associated Editors list. .js files should open in the Javascript Editor.

Comment: I don't have that actually... I had to add it like it said on the site. It's not one of the options offered. Do you know how to add it? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse Oxygen are you working with (exactly)? Click "About", a dialog should appear, telling "4.7.x ...". Pls report this by editing your question.

Comment: I just added it!

Answer (score 1):

You could give the latest [Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-09/r/eclipse-ide-javascript-and-web-developers) bundle a try.

It provides:

> The essential tools for any JavaScript developer, including JavaScript, HTML, CSS, XML languages support, Git client, and Mylyn.

With this recent (2018) version of Eclipse, you should get a working JS-enabled IDE pretty fast as this is pre-bundled for the use-cases you are looking for:

> - **JavaScript** Development Tools
> - Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
> - [..]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! I did add that before, but it did not do anything. I don't understand where it 'went' or what happened, but it did not change a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

FYI -- I ran into this problem with the latest version of eclipse [2020-06(4.16.0)]. It turns out they removed the Javascript editor from the install. See ref here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564496