# Unable to create JavaScript project in Eclipse (IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

[Image of project wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0bu3.png) I am not able to see the option to create a java script project or any type of project for that matter.

[here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-06/r/eclipse-ide-web-and-javascript-developers-includes-incubating-components) is the link where I downloaded the eclipse from.

Comment: Looks like a question for eclipse support, not here

Comment: Raising there as well but just wanted to make sure if is there anything I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was the answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse)

So unless you have JS library you can not create a JS project.