# Couldn't add javascript file in Spring tool suite(spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

My javascript file myChart.js displaying as a text file and not as a js File. What should I do to resolve it?

[CAn you please refer image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vowpI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Check if `JavaScript` syntax highlighting is enabled in **Eclipse/STS** as suggested [here](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_syntax_coloring.htm).

Alternatively, you can add marketplace plugins like [Code Mix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codemix-3).

Might need to **restart** to get the changes reflected.

Comment: hey, that was not eclipse. It is spring tool suite 4 for developing spring applications.How to enable javascript in that?

Comment: Options should be almost similar. STS is a flavour in top of Eclipse

Comment: I have the same problem. In Syntax Coloring of:
Web > HTML Files >Client-side JavaScript > Editor > Syntax 
Enable entry is disabled and not selected. 

How can I enable it?

Comment: @sunrelax, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269560/javascript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

We can install CodeMix plugin and from Eclipse Marketplace(Help -> Eclipse Marketplace) and it solves the problem.